# Tesseract fails to recognize big numbers if small number is close

Tags: javascript, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, price

We are using Tesseract.js for OCR'ing some product price tags. Some tags have an offer price fo the original price is stroked. The freaking thing is that we achieve to OCR the big price **only when there is no stroked price near**. But when there is a stroked price near, Tesseract doesn't identify the huge non-stroked number.

We are already using this parameter but we don't know how to deal with all the other hundreds of possible parameters:

```
Tesseract.recognize(blob, {
    tessedit_char_whitelist: '1234567890,€'
});
```

Those are the price tags we are trying to OCR - individually. We are focusing a single price tag at a same time with the smartphone camera.

[image]

Comment: How are you imaging them? Is it possible to crop to the numbers you want? Trying to OCR the entire image is probably not the way to go.

Comment: @user3169 added clarification

Comment: I don't think you can pick out the current price from the whole image, because the crossed out numeral is to the left of it (so Tesseract would try to recognize it first), and the other one is a different font size.

Comment: How about taking your image so it cuts off the top line or to the left of the number you want? Still I think modifying the image will be easier than trying to get Tesseract to pick out what you want.

Comment: "taking the image"

hmm it's the user who will point to the tag with its terminal, we can't control how the user focuses it

Comment: You might try asking this on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions). I think this needs a software solution, not simply a coding one. FWIW, ABBYY Finereader could OCR it OK, but then it's not free software.

Comment: @user3169 thank you for your kind comment. We need a JS library for this since it's for implementation on an Ionic app